# How to open Apple Music (iTunes) links in new Music app (MacOS Catalina)

Tags: macos, apple-music, apple-musickit

I have a web app that uses the [MusicKitJS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickitjs) together with Apple Music's API to display information about music releases. The behaviour since MacOS Catalina has changed due to the introduction of the Music app and removal of iTunes. Links like this one, that did open the album in iTunes, don't open in the Music App:

> https://music.apple.com/us/album/incredible-vice-ep/1491161925

I've done some digging on the above URL's page source, and noticed that if the `https://` is replaced with `itmss://`, then the album *does* open in the Music app:

> itmss://music.apple.com/us/album/incredible-vice-ep/1491161925

However, the behaviour seems to be broken:

- If the Music app is already open on the machine, then the clicking the above link from a browser will put the focus on the Music app, and then properly redirect to the relevant album.
- If the Music app isn't already open, then clicking the above link from a browser will launch the Music app, but it doesn't redirect to the relevant album.

Is there a way to both open the Music app if it isn't already open, and open the relevant album inside the app?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `musics://` scheme and add `app=itunes` as query parameter.

Taking your example this would result in:

```
musics://music.apple.com/us/album/incredible-vice-ep/1491161925?app=itunes
```

Comment: this link does not work on Andorid or Window OS, is there some similar link like this?